# Search and replace Vim 7.3

Tags: linux, vi

I'm trying to do a simple Search and Replace with vim 7.3. I'm receiving the `E486: Pattern not found: :%s`. I've also tried `:,$s/old/new/g` and I get the same error. What's really strange is that it only worked twice out about 50 or so tries.

If it helps, I'm using Kali Linux distro.

Comment: This could be a problem with sed binaries actually, is everything fine when you try sed out of vim context ?

Comment: Post the data examples; probably we could help you

Comment: @aduch I haven`t tried sed, I was working strictly in the vim editor. I`m rather new at this and was working through a Linux CLI book and hit a snag. What would the syntax be for a simple word search and replace from sed? Also @VitalyI the data is simply I have a text file with 5 instances of Line 1 through Line 5 and am attempting to substitute them with line 1 through 5. For example    `:%s/Line/line/g` or    `:.$/Line/line/g`

Comment: @Pantoriun `sed 's/old/new/' filename`

Comment: Oh god I figured it out. For some reason I was jumping in ex mode using / and starting my commands with that. Thanks @aduch for the attempts at helping my glaring stupidity.

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your problem, post it as an answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by starting an ex command with / rather than :. While forward slash will put you into ex command mode this particular issue of simple search and replace needed to be started with a colon.